# Docker. How to remove bind mounts between host and container?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container, docker-for-windows

I've started a Docker container with a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

```
docker run -it -v C:\host_folder:C:\container_folder mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022 powershell
```

I wanted to run a couple of `.exe` files from that folder to do some setup.

Once I've finished my work, I wanted to remove that bind mount. How do I do that?

I have tried to edit the following config files located in:

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers\<container identifier>
```

removing the part about bindings from both of them (`config.v2.json` and `hostconfig.json`) but after I restart the container, bind was still there and configs were restored.

I also created an image via

```
commit <container identifier> <new image name>:<new image tag>
```

After I ran a container based on this image, it also mounted a folder.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't remove a volume (or a bind mount) from a container. Could you perhaps tell us in more detail, what is it that you ultimately want to achieve? Do you just want to run something in a container, and have it save some output into a folder?

Comment: Are you trying to use those executables to create an image you can run later?  This sounds like a process that might be better run in a Dockerfile, without bind-mounting anything.

Comment: @JanezKuhar mentioned `.exe` files are actually a bunch of .NET tools to run a dev studio to build an exportable package as an artifact for the gitlab ci. So you're right

Comment: @DavidMaze I assume I dont really need an image - just a single container which I can start whenever i need it. But if container won't be enough I will make it as you say

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a running process, and you need the image to create new containers as you need them.  You should create the image by installing tools in a Dockerfile (and commit that to source control) and running `docker build`.